# How to word the concept of "technical knowledge consultant"

Tags: resume, training, mentoring

I have a position as a Data Scientist within a very large team (60+ people).
Six of them are business intelligence technicians/data analysts/data scientists/whatever you want to call them.

Career wise I am their senior, but they do not report to me.

One of my roles is to train them in data science, but also to be a mentor with respect to all things data.
In addition to/as part of this, I'm also supposed to help them with certain technical aspects of their roles (automation of reports, scripting, data analysis, ...).

I want a short way of describing the second part of the above paragraph on my CV. As of now I describe it as "Technical knowledge consultant", but the wording seems odd to me. I'm not a native English speaker, but my CV is in English.

The relevant part of my CV looks like this:

- Mentor to junior colleagues

  1. Training content writing and training;
  2. Technical knowledge consultant.

To formalize my question. How can I best describe `2.` above in a short way?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thank you for the question. Perhaps I do not need it. It would be consistent with the rest of my CV, though.

Comment: Using some term to describe it will probably leave what you actually did very ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest "Technical trainer" or "Technical coach". We have a Technical Coach at work and your description quite matches her responsibilities.

Answer (score 4):

The term most I most commonly see for this is [Subject Matter Expert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert).

> A subject-matter expert (SME) or domain expert is a person who is an authority in a particular area or topic. The term domain expert is frequently used in expert systems software development, and there the term always refers to the domain other than the software domain. A domain expert is a person with special knowledge or skills in a particular area of endeavour (e.g. an accountant is an expert in the domain of accountancy). The development of accounting software requires knowledge in two different domains: accounting and software. Some of the development workers may be experts in one domain and not the other.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know of this term. It's not clear to me that it is a good choice though. They actually have more domain knowledge than me (i,e, they know more about retail as a whole (I work in retail)). Even if it is correct, I'm afraid it might mislead anyone who reads my CV. EDIT. And I understand that one might look at the technical aspects of data science as them being the *domain*, but would readers understand this?

Comment: @consultant - SME's are not know everythings, they are just people who have knowledge and know how to research answers.  But good luck what ever you choose.

Comment: SMEs are expected to be very knowledgeable within their SM, with no expectations outside of it (related to the SME designation, at least). If the OP's specialty is in data science and he or she is responsible for transmitting that knowledge to others, then he or she almost certainly is a SME in the data science space.